# Web server that encrypts uploaded files, can withstand compromised server & decrypt to multiple users

Tags: security, encryption, web, cryptography

There are generally 2 main methods of encrypting user uploaded files.

The client can encrypt the file, send it over for the server to store, and on request the server retrieves the encrypted file and the client does the decryption. In this scenario, the server never has access to the keys. There are cons to this; the encryption scheme is viewable by anyone in the source of the web app, it's extra processing for the client, and others

The second scenario of course is when the client sends the file in plaintext (presumably over SSL), and the server manages the keys and encryption/decryption.

It seems to me that the most common form implemented is the latter, where the server manages the encryption/decryption for the client. This seems ineffectual to me. If the web server is compromised, even if the attacker just has web app level privileges, encryption in the first place was pointless since he will have access to all the keys just as the web app did, and thereby the decrypted files. Is there a way to prevent this? Why would people even encrypt files to begin with then, unless they did client-side encryption and never store the keys?

Also, as a second part to this question, is it feasible to allow multiple people access to an encrypted file (say a division within a company) if you used the former option (client-side encryption)? I would presume the users would have to share their keys among themselves, which poses another security risk.

Comment: The purpose of the encryption aspect of SSL is just to prevent anyone being able to read the communication between the client and server, not to save you from uploading things to a malicious server (which would fall more into the identification aspect that identifies the server is who it claims to be). And its not all about "files" but the HTTP request and response.

Comment: Absolutely. Not what I was asking though. I'm not interested in handling malicious files either (that will be handled on it's own and is an entirely different task). I'm only interested in storing the file securely without exposing the keys to an attack if the web app is compromised.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Alright, I'll post it there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SSL only protects connection. If you want to prevent server from peeking at yours files, the file must be encrypted by a secret key server does not know. (scenario one)

For the second part, There are many [papers](http://dcg.ethz.ch/publications/srds06.pdf) discussing how to build such systems based on public key cryptography. Or you may look into other recently crypto reserches, such as [broadcast encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_encryption) or [attribute-based encryption.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_encryption)

Comment: Using public key crypto is not feasible because it's too complicated for a normal user to implement. I'll lose usership.

I'm assuming there's no way to do the encryption server-side while keeping the keys safe from an attack